# Switch statement in function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I've written a menu which will feed an integer into the selectPod function and then I want the $sqlSettings object populated with Server and database to use in a few SQL Queries I've written later in the script.
I've done the tricky bits but can't seem to get this working.

```
$SQLServer = @()
$Server = @()
$database = @()
function selectPod($podnumber) {
       switch ($podnumber)
            {
                1 {  $Server = "SQLSERVER01";
                     $Database = "DATABASE01"
                    }

                2 {  $Server = "SQLSERVER02";
                     $Database = "DATABASE02"
                    }

                3 {  $Server = "SQLSERVER03";
                     $Database = "DATABASE03"}

                4 {  $Server = "SQLSERVER04";
                     $Database = "DATABASE04"}

                5 {  $Server = "SQLSERVER05"
                     $Database = "DATABASE05"}
            }
            $properties =  $params = @{
                           'Pod' = $podnumber;
                           'SQLServer' = $Server;
                           'Database' = $Database;
            }
            $sqlSettings = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
            Write-Output $sqlSettings
}

selectPod 5


Write-Host "you are targeting " $($SQLSettings.POD) " which is SQLServer`
                 $($SQLSettings.server) and $($SQLSettings.database)" -ForegroundColor Green
```

I know it's working becuase the write output is fine. But the write-host show's it's not surviving outside the function.

```
you are targeting    which is SQLServer  and 
SQLServer   Pod Database  
---------   --- --------  
SQLSERVER05   5 DATABASE05
```

I'm probably doing this completely the wrong way but any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: you are running into a scoping problem. [*grin*] you need to assign the output of `selectpod 5` to SOMETHING and then use that in your operations out side of the function. ///// it may be tempting to manually abuse the scoping system with `$Scope;VarName` ... but that is almpst always the wrong thing to do since it makes tracking the source of problems very, very difficult.

Comment: Yeah thanks I've been tripped up by scope before so need to re-read that so it sinks in. Thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! as for scopes - one way to think of them is as boxes. the outer box cannot see what is created in the inner ones ... but the inner ones can _see_ what the outer one had when the inner one was created.

Comment: Ah nice one thanks good analogy

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables within a function are confined to the function unless you declare otherwise.
Either assign a script/global variable to the result e.g. $Global:SQLSettings - or a better way is to return your value from the function as an object.

Replace `Write-Output $sqlSettings` 
With `Return $sqlSettings`

...and look at the value returned when you run the function e.g.

```
$Result = selectPod 5
```

Comment: Massive facepalm slap. I don't know how many PowerShell scope videos I've watched and they always say Scope trips people up. I understand function scope now. Thanks. this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Move your Write-Host command into the switch block. If you want to use the output object for anything else, collect it in a variable like this:

```
$sqlSettings = selectpod 5
```